# Failed to lookup path nodejs

Tags: nodejs

Soy nuevo con Node JS y tengo en serio muchas dudas, ahora intento crear mis propias my static files para el servidor, esta es mi esstructura de archivos

```
   -ship.io
      -node_modules
      -public
        -api
        -css
        -images
        -js
        -views
   -server.js
   -package.json
```

y esta es mi configuracion de path

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/')));
app.use('/img',express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/views')));
app.use('/js',express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/js')));
app.use('/css',express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/css')));
```

Pero cuando hago

```
app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('index.ejs',{
        Title: "ship.io"
    });
});
```

obtengo este erro :'c

**Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory**

Comment: y si pruebas en la parte de __dirname que quede asi:__dirname+'/public/views'

Comment: Sigue diciemdome el mismo error

Comment: tengo el mismo inconveniente, pudiste encontrar alguna solución?. Saludos